# Transparent button on click

Tags: android, xml

How can I make my Button Transparent when the user clicks it so the user knows that he cliked the button keep in mind that I made an xml file to let the button corners rounded here is the xml code I used I just want the button color to be transparent while clicking the button but nothing shuld happen to the text the text must be visible all the time just the button color become transparent and of course the button color return back after the user clicks it

```
<solid android:color="#d9d9d9"/>
<corners
    android:bottomRightRadius="15dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="15dp"
    android:topRightRadius="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by defining a selector to your button that defines the background color for the button on different statuses.

In the drawable folder, add your_button.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/button_background_on_pressed"/> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@color/button_background"/> <!-- default -->
```

and set your button background to this drawable

```
android:background="@drawable/your_button"
```